# Selecting variations in Nokogiri

Tags: html, css, ruby, nokogiri

I'm scraping these two sites:

1. https://www.library.uq.edu.au/uqlsm/availablepcsembed.php?branch=Law
2. https://www.library.uq.edu.au/uqlsm/availablepcsembed.php?branch=BSL.

Unfortunately, they have variations. One has the level name (Eg. Level 2) inside a `href` tag, while the other one is just plain text. How can I select one or the other depending which one is there?

I tried this to no avail:

```
level.css(/"a[href]"|".left"/).text
```

**Here are shortened versions of the 2 HTML sections:**

```
<table class="chart"> 
    <tr valign="middle">
        <td class="left">Level 2</td> <!-- the problem -->
        <td class="middle"><div style="width:86%;"><strong>86%</strong></div></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

```
<table class="chart">
    <tr valign="middle">
        <td class="left"><a href="availablepcsembed.php?branch=BSL&room=Lvl1">Level 1</a></td>
        <td class="middle"><div style="width:32%;"><strong>32%</strong></div></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**My Code** (edited from section of code to whole method)

```
def self.scrape_details_page(library_url)
    details_page = Nokogiri::HTML(open(library_url))

    details_page.css("table.chart tr").collect do |level|
        right = level.css(".right").text.split
        {level: level.css("a[href]").text, available: right[0], out_of_available: right[3]}
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to inspiration from @jk_ I fixed it using `.css(".left").text`. That just selects all the text in the left `td` inside the `tr`.

The working code:

```
def self.scrape_details_page(library_url)
    details_page = Nokogiri::HTML(open(library_url))

    details_page.css("table.chart tr").collect do |level|
        right = level.css(".right").text.split
        {level: level.css(".left").text, available: right[0], out_of_available: right[3]}
    end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

If what you want to do is grab the text that is within the innermost div, you should be able to dive all the way down just by calling `#text` on the parsed `td` element. No need to account for and walk extra tags that might be present inside, e.g. the link tag. Given your code as written:

```
details_page.css("table.chart tr").collect do |level|
     level = level.text
end
```

For each element, that would pull the level label or percentage value (inner text) as a string and assign the value to the levels variable.

Edit: also, if all you care about is getting the level label, you can just filter the elements by class up front:

```
details_page.css("table.chart tr td.left").collect do |level|
     level = level.text
end
```

Comment: I fixed my original post to reflect the full method so it is easier to understand. Using `.text` would work but makes it harder to work with seeing as it returns this: `"\r\n" + "                Level 1\r\n" + "                42%\r\n" + "                13 Free of 31 PC's\r\n" + "                "`. My answer below uses `.css(".left").text` and that seems to select exactly what i need. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The [answer by jk_](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46996404/7151673) should work in this particular case.

In the more general case, if you're going to use a CSS selector, you need to use CSS syntax for "or" (a comma). So if you were going to use the selectors you originally asked about, it'd be

```
level.css('a[href], .left').text
```

Comment: Is there a way to do one or the other? That is what I was looking for except instead of selecting both, I wanted it to select one of the two depending on which was found.

Comment: You're going to get back all the elements that match either one. In your case, the second format has examples of both `a[href]` and `.left`. So you have to pick different selectors (as with jk_'s answer that uses just `.left`) or decide which of the elements to use. You can use `.at_css` if you just want the first element.